Detect Discord bot pings in Python
How can I detect if a discord message contains any mention that would ping the bot?
In another thread I saw that you can use client.user.mentioned_in(message), but this doesn't seem to recognize role pings. Is there any catch-all way to detect any mentions that ping the bot?

You can use the message.mentions and message.role_mentions attributes to check:
me = message.guild.me # bot's member
if me in message.mentions or any(role in message.role_mentions for role in me.roles):
    ... # bot has been mentioned

PS: Remember to have guild, member and message content intents enabled.
